# getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS on NSString. Log says Invalid CFStringRef

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to access data from a server that i set up. 
While 4 files are worked perfectly, i am getting an Thread2: Program recieved signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

```
-(void)loadContentInBackground
{

        NSError *error;

        NSString *posterURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@PartyCentral/WeeklyParties/Club%@/poster.jpg",baseURL,clubNum];

        poster.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:posterURL]]];

        posterEnlarged.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:posterURL]]];

        NSString *vp1URL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@PartyCentral/WeeklyParties/Club%@/VenuePic/pic1.jpg",baseURL,clubNum];
        venuePic1.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:vp1URL]]];

        NSString *vp2URL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@PartyCentral/WeeklyParties/Club%@/VenuePic/pic2.jpg",baseURL,clubNum];
        venuePic2.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:vp2URL]]];

        NSString *vp3URL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@PartyCentral/WeeklyParties/Club%@/VenuePic/pic3.jpg",baseURL,clubNum];
        venuePic3.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:vp3URL]]];


        NSString *nameURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@PartyCentral/WeeklyParties/Club%@/name.txt",baseURL,clubNum];
        NSString *nameData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:nameURL] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
        name.text = nameData;

        // Date Being downloaded.
        NSString *dateURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@PartyCentral/WeeklyParties/Club%@/date.txt",baseURL,clubNum];
        NSString *dateData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dateURL] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
        date.text = dateData;

        // Day Being downloaded. THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR COMES IN HIGHLIGHTING THE
       //initWithFormat line


        NSString *dayURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@PartyCentral/WeeklyParties/Club%@/day.txt",baseURL,clubNum];
        NSString *dayData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dayURL] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
        day.text = dayData;

        // Latitude & Longitude Being downloaded. 
        NSString *latitudeURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@PartyCentral/WeeklyParties/Club%@/Location/latitude.txt"];
        NSString *latitudeData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:latitudeURL] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];

        NSString *longitudeURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%dPartyCentral/WeeklyParties/Club%@/Location/longitude.txt",baseURL,clubNum];
        NSString *longitudeData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:longitudeURL] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
        location.latitude = [latitudeData doubleValue];
        location.longitude = [longitudeData doubleValue];

        MapAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:[name text] andCoordinate:location];
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
        [newAnnotation release];

    }
```

in the log next to the dayURL i get, invalid CFStringRef.

Please Help...!

Comment: check dayURL has value or not?

Comment: dayURL shows no value... In the log it says invalid CFStringRef. And the app crashes when it reaches this line of the code

Comment: Problem is Either of them baseURL or clubNum has no value or not properly specified according to your request. if both of them has value and request might not work as baseURL or clubNum is not properly set for requesting data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
NSString *latitudeURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@PartyCentral/WeeklyParties/Club%@/Location/latitude.txt"];
```

Contains a formatting string with no arguments supplied, which is will have the effect of dereferencing whatever values are on the stack.  If those *pointers* aren't to valid memory then this type of error will occur.